# Is it haram to give up life because of guilt?

Tags: fiqh, suicide

Suppose there was a train which caught fire. A person's wife and kid died due to the fire but husband survived and had the chance to leave the train cabin through a broken window but he did not saying "My wife and child is inside, dead. How can I leave without them." And he was burnt alive in the train cabin with his family.

I know that if a person dies due to fire he is considered a martyr, this is for the wife and child. But what about the husband? Will his cause be considered suicide? Is this haram, the thing he did?

Comment: Waiting for an explanation based on Islam! What I understand is that the man gave up his live in despair, which I, myself, find understandable by way of humans are, but still it looks like throwing away the live Allah has given. Before anyone downvotes: this question is quite obviously *not* seeking personal advice.

Comment: In what way is [survivor guilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_guilt) considered a "moral cause"?

Answer (score 1):

Allowing oneself to die because of sadness for the loss of loved ones is a form of suicide and is forbidden.

> ولا تقتلوا أنفسكم إن الله كان بكم رحيما
>
> And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:29](https://quran.com/4/29?translations=20)</sup>

Suicide is not only achieved by action but also by refraining from action.

> يجب على المرء أن يعمل على استحياء نفسه ما استطاع إلى ذلك سبيلا، ويكون ذلك بأمرين: أولهما: بدفع التلف عنها بإزالة سببه، كالجوع والعطش ، وإطفاء الحريق أو الهرب منه، كما إذا احترقت سفينة ولم يمكن إطفاؤها، وغلب على الظن أن ركابها لو ألقوا أنفسهم في الماء نجوا، وجب عليهم ذلك
>
> It is obligatory to try to keep oneself alive to the best of one's ability. And this can be through two ways:
>
> First: By defending against death by removing its means such as hunger, thirst, extinguishing a fire or running away from it, for example if a boat catches fire and it is not possible to extinguish it and it is thought most likely that if the passengers jump into the water they would save themselves then it is obligatory to do that.
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/1809)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have another question in mind, which is, years back Muslims had to fight the Byzantines, Khaled ibn Waleed was in dire situation. Ikrimah decided to do a suicide run to give the Muslims a chance to survive. 
The verse of the Holy Quran which has been mentioned in connection with the right to life, Allah has said: "And whoever saves a life it is as though he had saved the lives of all mankind" (5:32).
So, this will be considered jihad right? Because this was a religious battle and he died so more people can live and carry on. How do we understand this matter?

Comment: Tangential questions should be asked separately, not in the comments. It is permitted to sacrifice oneself in Jihad [Quran 4:74](https://quran.com/4/74?translations=20), [Quran 9:111](https://quran.com/9/111?translations=20) the question you are asking does not have any relevance to that.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I am new here so I didn't know that. And thank you very much for the insight, helped a lot!